# How to tag a image(.tar) file of docker(container) while loading into other host?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, containers

I have configured a Docker image locally on my machine with `tags` which consist of WordPress on it. I have uploaded this image to AWS S3 bucket and pulled the image from AWS EC2.

My issue is when I load the `xxxx.tar.gz` on my EC2 instance

```
docker load -i xxxxx.tar.gz
```

it gets loaded but, the repository `name` and `tag` shows `none`

```
REPOSITORY     TAG     IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
none           none    271c6bafbc36        2 days ago          406.7 MB
```

Can anyone please tell me that how we can load an image(`.tar.gz`) file with predefined `name` and `tags`

Answer (score 0):

You have to tag it, see `docker tag`, and the doc

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/tag/

```
docker tag [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [REGISTRYHOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]
```

Tag an image into a repository

```
-f, --force=false    Force
```

Comment: I had already tagged the image but while loading the image in other instance it doesn't load the existing tag.